# How to show file list in a ordered way from SFTP server?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to connect to the SFTP server and want to show the file-list in a ordered way. But the result is coming in a haphazard manner. Filename are in a manner of '20190920_XYZ'. So how to make this in a order way? Please suggest.

```
SftpClient sftpConnection = new 
SftpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPServer"], PORT, "UserName", "Password");

sftpConnection.Connect();

var toReturn = sftpConnection.ListDirectory("/.....path").ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour], and [mcve] .. what exactly is the structure in toReturn, what have you tried?

Comment: in toReturn, i am receiving the values in a list but i want this to be in a ordered manner(like in the SFTP ) as it is .

Comment: so sort that returned list, some apps auto sort it for you, how exactly are you comparing what  you see with what you expect

Comment: in the server it shows some data in such a manner "20190920_ABCD"

Comment: ok on the sever, which then has an sftp peice of software, that talks to a client sftp peice of software .. its not too surprising its not the same.. which sftpclient stuff are you using?

Comment: in the server it shows some data in such a manner '20190920_ABCD' , '20190910_ABCD', '20190909_ABCD'  but here I am getting in haphazard manner .

Comment: i am using using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;

Comment: Well if its a list of strings you can sort it, but, looking through the github it suggests that the sftpfile list thats returned contains dates, and other attributes, so you can sort it to whatever requirement you like

Answer (score 0):

Add sort to the ToList() command: -

var toReturn = sftpConnection.ListDirectory("/.....path").ToList()**.Sort()**;